# A letter sequence problem

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations, combinatorics-on-words

If I have an $8$ letter string of the letters $C$ and $N$, how many ways can I arrange the letters so that no two N's are adjacent to each other?

Comment: Welcome to MSE ^_^. What have you tried? We can help you better when we have a better idea of exactly where you're stuck. Moreover, a lot of people on this website take offense when it looks like someone wants us to do their homework for them, and showing that you've put in some effort will make people more likely to respond

Comment: @HallaSurvivor Take offense is really an extreme term, don't you think? XD, although I really support your point. bobjoe12 please show your effort

Comment: Not really, no.

Comment: I realized that there are 256 total combinations, and that there are certain sequences that make casework tricky... I was wondering if I need to use PIE/complimentary counting

Comment: Btw this isnt my homework im working on writing a problem

Comment: Thanks for the downvote btw that will really get me the help i need

Comment: @bobjoe12 Think about recursion.

Comment: If you are working on writing a problem, the first thing you should realize is that the answer heavily depends on exactly which 8 letter string you have. If you have $5$ or more $N$'s, the answer is just $0$, for example.And there aren't 256 combinations, just $9$: number of $N$'s can be $0,1,\ldots, 8$, that determines the number of $C$'s and so completely the letters you have to work with.If you have $4$ $N$'s, it doesn't matter if your original word was $CCCCNNNN$, $NNNNCCCC$ or $CNNCCNNC$ or something else.

Answer (score 1):

Here we derive a recurrence relation. We consider words of length $n$ built from an alphabet $\{C,N\}$ and denote the number of valid words with $a_n$.

We obtain a recurrence relation for $a_{n+1}$ by partitioning valid words of length $n+1$ into two disjoint sets.

- **Termination with $C$:** A word of length $n+1$ may end with the letter $C$. In this case we have $a_n$ possibilities to fill the left-most $n$ positions with valid words.
- **Termination with $N$:** If on the other hand the word terminates with $N$ it terminates in fact with $CN$, since $NN$ is not admissible. We have therefore $a_{n-1}$ possibilities to fill the $n-1$ left-most positions with valid words of length $n-1$.
  We obtain the recurrence relation
  \begin{align*}
  \color{blue}{a_{n+1}=a_n+a_{n-1}\qquad\qquad n\geq 1}
  \end{align*}
  It is easy to determine the initial conditions, since the valid words of length $n=1$ are $\{C,N\}$ and $n=2$ are $\{CC,CN,NC\}$, so that $\color{blue}{a_1=2}$ and $\color{blue}{a_2=3}$.

> We finally get Fibonacci-numbers $a_n$:
> \begin{align*}
> \begin{array}{r|rrrrrrrr}
> n&1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8\\
> a_n&2&3&5&8&13&21&34&\color{blue}{55}\\
> \end{array}
> \end{align*}
> and conclude there are $\color{blue}{a_8=55}$ valid words of length $8$.